# EDIT DATA in TABLE using php

Tags: php, mysqli

---

### **I want to edit data in my table using modal but i can only call ID=1 i cant edit the others and also i need to refresh my web before i can see the changes?

// my update code

```
    <?php
    $id= "1";
    $mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root','','books');
    $query = $mysqli->query("select * from bookrecords where ID='$id' ");
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
    if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $nm = $_POST['nm'];
      $is = $_POST['is'];
      $pb = $_POST['pb'];
      $au = $_POST['au'];
      $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE bookrecords set BookName='$nm', ISBN='$is', Publisher='$pb', Author='$au' where ID='$id'");
      if($result){ 
        ?>  

    <div class="alert-success" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times</span></button>
      <strong>Success!</strong> your data has been updated.
      </div>

      <?php
    } else{
    ?>

     <div class="alert-failed" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times</span></button>
      <strong>Failed!</strong> Error updating. Try Again!
      </div>


       <?php
       }
     }
       ?>
```

** and this is my Modal form....

```
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="id">ID:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['ID']?>" readonly>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nm">BookName:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nm" name="nm" value="<?php echo $row['BookName']?>">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="is">ISBN:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="is" name="is" value="<?php echo $row['ISBN']?>">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pb">Publisher:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pb" name="pb" value="<?php echo $row['Publisher']?>">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="au">Author:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="au" name="au" value="<?php echo $row['Author']?>">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn-primary">Update</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </form>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">

  </div>
</div>
```

**so how can i call any of my item/data in table? Please help me.

Comment: Pass the id in a hidden field within the form maybe? You really should take a look at how to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) because security is a real threat here.

Comment: Also, not sure if you knew this but `$id= "1";` is a string and `$id= 1;` is an integer. Won't really change anything in your code but will be useful if you use prepared statments!

Comment: ok thanks.. i know that $id= "1"; but what i can get is i want my $id= to any ID in my table/database so i can edit any data in my table.. :) appreciate ur help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML form must have a hidden field with the id of book record, which will be send to the PHP script when pressing the "Update" button. The hidden field should look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="bookrecordId" value="ID_OF_BOOKRECORD_HERE" />
```

You can access the value of the transfered id with `$_POST['bookrecordId']` in your receiving PHP script. Use it to build one or two [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) which will check if the row exists and then run an UPDATE query to update the values.

Comment: THank u for your answer but It has a hidden field already and actually i can update already sir my problem right now is that i can only update 1 data/item which is because my $id = '1'; i dont know how can i edit another item with different ID like for example my second data which has id=2

Comment: @KhunAgnis You don't write `$id = 1;` hard coded in your code. Instead you use such a hidden field and use the value in `$_POST['bookrecordId']` instead. This way the "Update" action is meant only for the specific book record where you pressed the "Update" button.

Comment: ah okay then what value wil i give to this ("SELECT * from bookrecords where ID='$id' "); do i need to make this where ID = "$_POST['ID']"?

Comment: also sir this is my hidden field <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['ID']?>">

Comment: @KhunAgnis Then you have the value in `$_POST['id']` and can use it like any other variable. Keep in mind to use "prepared statements" for SQL queries which has a variable input.

Comment: ok thanks.. i think i just redo my codes.. but i feel like something is missing with this code $row = $query->fetch_assoc();

Comment: @KhunAgnis It depends on what you current code is. You might need an `execute()` call to execute your prepared statement. However, this will be a new different question and is not related to this problem.